# HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys in ASP.NET CORE version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext, invalidoperationexception

```
foreach (string key in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
   string value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[key];
}
```

What is the .net core version of the above code? Seems like .net core took out **AllKeys** and replaced it with **Keys** instead. I tried to convert the above code to the .net core way, but it throws an invalid operation exception.

> HttpContext.Request.Form = 'HttpContext.Request.Form' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Converted code:

```
foreach (string key in HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys)
{      
}
```

Comment: What's the message of the exception?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your could use this:

```
var dict = Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());
```

In that case, you can iterate over your dictionary or you can access values directly:

```
dict["Hello"] = "World"
```

Comment: var result= dict["Hello"] ;

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
StringValues s; 

Request.Form.TryGetValue("KeyName", out s);
if (s.Count == 1)
 {
   string value = s.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());

foreach (var item in data)
{
    if (item.Key.Contains("hello"))
    {
        // ?
    }
    else if (item.Key.Contains("world"))
    {
        // ?
    }
}
```